# Google Maps v2 MapFragment on Fragment Tab project fails on android 2.3

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2, android-tabs

Hi I have a Fragment Tab project.
When I go to Map tab (a custom MapFragment), It works ok, but when I change to another tab the new fragment appears only at zoom controls of the google maps. When I go back to Map tab, all show ok. It's only happen when I go to Map tab, If I never use Map tab, the others fragments works ok.

I attach some screenshots of my problem

[image: Map tab]

[image: Changing to another tab]

How I can solve this problem?

Comment: I'd suggest to post some code.

Comment: Had same problem...got any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem it's only with android 2 and with devices that not support opengl 2.0. I've added

```
<uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>
```

To manifest file